# Dependency Error: DependencyNotInstalled: No module named 'mujoco_py'

Tags: python, anaconda, openai-gym, mujoco

I am using the information available on the following link to install and enable Mujoco and gym[all] dependencies.
https://medium.com/@sayanmndl21/install-openai-gym-with-box2d-and-mujoco-in-windows-10-e25ee9b5c1d5
I went through all the steps successfully until:
pip install gym[all]
Here I am getting the following two errors in the command prompt:
1 - "Running setup.py install for box2d-py ... error"
2 - "Running setup.py install for mujoco-py ... error"

["Running setup.py install for box2d-py ... error"
][1]

["Running setup.py install for mujoco-py ... error"][2]

I was able to load Cart-Pole environment but I got the following error when tried to open 'Fetch Reach-v1' environment:

" DependencyNotInstalled: No module named 'mujoco_py'. (HINT: you need to install mujoco_py, and also perform the setup instructions here: https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/.)".

Comment: Did you do this part? `perform the setup instructions here: https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/.` - A license is required to install/use this modile

Comment: I have a student license for Mujoco. Also, I am using Windows 10 and Mujoco 2.0.0 is not available for Windows and I think this is I am facing trouble installing it.

Comment: I have tried the steps mentioned in this repository and still seeing the same error. I can see mujoco-py installed in 'conda list' of my environment but I am unable to render any mujoco environment.

Comment: Yep - if Windows is no longer supported, your onlt options may be to look into a linux VM or try ´One known good past version is 1.50.1.68.´